# Copy File from Private Directory to public sub Directory in android 11 ( R )

Tags: android, file, kotlin, storage

I am saving file in application private storage, which includes images, video and audio. I have a requirement to give option in application to export all multimedia files to public directory so user can see their multimedia files whenever they want. I want to do this operation in background. I know we cannot create root directory in android 11 we have to use media Store API to save our file in sub directory same like whats app doing. But i am not being able to find any helpful material how to copy files with media Store. can any one help me to find some helpful material ??

any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> > I know we cannot create root directory in android 11

Indeed.

But you can create your own directories in all public folders like

```
Download
Documents
DCIM
Pictures
...
```

And then you can copy as before.

Comment: blackapps to create own Directory Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory is deprecated. i am looking for alternative codebase

Comment: Then use the MediaStore to insert() files in for instance .RELATIVE_PATH Documents\MyFolder and .DISPLAY_NAME MyFile.txt.

Comment: thanks for helping. actually i know how to create new file with media store API. but don't getting idea how to copy file from one path to other path with Media Store.

Comment: I dont understand. If you can use the mediastore to create a file you get an uri with insert() and you would write content to that uri. You just have to read the content from the original file.

Comment: one more question. I have to move/copy my external files to internal storage. how can i do ?? how can i read external storage directory and create its URI for MediaStore

Comment: I do again not understand what you want. You cannot use the MediaStore for internal storage. Only for external.

Comment: actually i want to migrate my data from external storage to internal storage so when app will run on android 11 it will use that directory to get files. which were previously stored in external storage. if i will not do this action application will not be able to get that files from internal storage.

Comment: From external you mean.

Comment: from Shared storage ( root directory in device storage ) to private storage ( inside app data folder )

Comment: My god... If you say `migrate my data from external storage to internal storage` and then `will not be able to get that files from internal storage`  and if i then reply with `From external you mean` Then say yes or no and dont come with other descriptions as there was only external and internal.

Comment: sorry if i am confusing you. Till android 10 my files were saved in Shared Storage ( root directory in device storage ) for that i were using getExternalStorageDirecotory()

now i am targeting my app to android 11 (30 SDK)
an using app private storage.   like getExternalFilesDir(null) to save files 

now when same user will install android 11 version. it will not be able to get files which are already in Shared storage. Like in getExternalStorageDirecotory()

so what should be the procedure so user files are move on private storage so whenever he/she want to get files it will be there

Comment: Wel move them from external to internal. But your subject suggests you want to move from internal to external. So its a mess here. My answer is for your subject. And now you want the reverse.

Comment: Copy them first. After that delete original files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237048/discussion-between-rizwan-rasheed-and-blackapps).